# How To Get Multiline Text Box to Render Environment.NewLine Correctly?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am unable to get a multiline text box to render strings separated by Environment.NewLine as strings on multiple lines.

I am querying a database and receiving back a string that is pipe delimited text (for example 123|456|789).

I want to parse that text and put it into a multi-line text box on a Windows Form application.  I am parsing the text and doing a replace | with Environment.NewLine.  In the text box the string is rendered on one line this way: 123456789.  However, when you copy/paste the text out of the box it is correctly parsed (it will have 123 on line 1, 456 on line 2, 789 on line 3).

I want the text to render in the text box with line breaks.

I have tried parsing the string in different ways (using a StringBuilder).  I have tried explicitly setting the textbox to multiline = true.

I am parsing the string this way (where orabddr is my Data Reader from the database):

```
txtTracking.Text = oradbdr.GetString(11).Replace("|", Environment.NewLine);
```

I want my multiline text box to reflect where the Environment.NewLine characters are.

Comment: Happens when the Multiline property isn't set to *true*.

Comment: Thanks for the followup.  In my form load method I'm calling this:  txtTracking.Multiline = true;  Is there another way I should set it?

Comment: Belongs in the constructor, setting it in the designer with the Properties window is the most logical way to do it.

Comment: Thank you - I've done that as well and there is no change.

Comment: I made a troubleshooting step doing this:  

`//txtTracking.Text = oradbdr.GetString(11).Replace("|", Environment.NewLine);` 
 
`txtTracking.Text = "Hello";`  

`txtTracking.Text = txtTracking.Text + Environment.NewLine;`  

`txtTracking.Text = txtTracking.Text + "World";`  

And this renders correctly in the UI.  It would seem my properties of my text box are correctly set - it is something about how the data reader is placing the text in the box?

Comment: *This* doesn't work either - what in the *@#$$? This is still rendering the box with no split:  `string delimitedTrack = oradbdr.GetString(11);
                    string[] arrayTrack = delimitedTrack.Split('|');
                    foreach (string track in arrayTrack) {
                        txtTracking.Text = txtTracking.Text + Environment.NewLine + track;
                    }`

Comment: Geez - so sorry...  I just realized my issue and it's the dumbest thing in the world.  I was told this was piped text and it's not (the database function I'm even calling is "tracking_numbers_piped").  It was delimited by chr(10) and that's why when I copied/pasted outside the box it looked like it was parsing correctly.  Once that was fixed all works as expected.  I feel as stupid as this sounds.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your string is actually delimited how you've been told.

Comment: Upvoted, as this actually turned out to be the answer (even though it should have originally been a comment to the OP).